# Redux not working with React-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm using the following:

react v16.2.0,
react-redux v5.0.7,
react-router-dom v4.2.2,
redux v3.7.2

What I am trying to achieve is to update some props from the `Auth` component, and when the user navigates to `/user` (Which loads the `Userpage` component), the modified props should be displayed.
Here is a simplified version of my code:

In App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Store from './components/Store';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Auth from './components/auth';
import Userpage from './components/Userpage';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (  
      <Provider store={Store}>    
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/login" component={Auth}/>
            <Route path="/user" component={Userpage}/>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In Store.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const reducer = (state,action) => {
    if(action.type == 'TEST'){
        return Object.assign({},state,{test:action.payload.test});
    } else    
        return state;
}

export default createStore(reducer,{
    test:'DOES NOT WORK',
})
```

In Auth.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Userpage from './Userpage';


class Auth extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.update('TEST',{test:'WORKS'});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Userpage/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    (store) => {
        return store;
    },
    (dispatch) => {
        return {
            update:(dispatchType, dispatchPayload) => {
                dispatch({type:dispatchType,payload:dispatchPayload});
            }
        }
    }
)(Auth);
```

In Userpage.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Userpage extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.props.test);
    }

    render(){
            return null;
    }
}

export default connect(
    (store) => {
        return store;
    }
)(Userpage);
```

Now, when I navigate to /login, the store is updated and `test` is set to "WORKS". But if I navigate to /userpage, `console.log(this.props.test)` prints "DOES NOT WORK", instead of the updated prop.

Just to test, I included `Userpage` in the render function of `Auth` and it console logs "WORKS" correctly.

So why is the redux store apparently being reset to default values on navigation to another page using react-router? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Apparently the whole application re-renders when you manually navigate (by typing in the URL in the browser), hence resetting the redux store.

Using `Link` as mentioned in react-router docs or redirecting using `this.props.history.push('/user')` works without any issues.